# Cannot mount a drive as read-write Fedora 26

Tags: fedora, fstab

I just switched from a fedora 25 machine to a fedora 26, and for some reason, I cannot mount the same drives as read/write.  This "d_drive" is a physical SSD connected via SATA.  I'm able to mount USB connected SSD drives as read/write, but for some reason, this SATA connected drive is only mounting as read-only.
 There's fstab entries are almost identical b/t the 2 installations

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/fc7ba0e3-9426-4695-a723-c2d960bf3b21 /mnt/d_drive auto rw,nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

after mounting, I see this from dmesg:

```
[62156.594073] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x480001 action 0x6 frozen
[62156.594080] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[62156.594085] ata3: SError: { RecovData 10B8B Handshk }
[62156.594091] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[62156.594100] ata3.00: cmd 61/08:00:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 4096 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[62156.594105] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[62156.594112] ata3: hard resetting link
[62157.053978] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[62157.054211] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[62157.054583] ata3.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[62157.054902] ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[62157.055300] ata3.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
[62157.055311] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33
[62157.055325] ata3: EH complete
[62194.475214] EXT4-fs (sdb1): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[62194.479586] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

When I try running the following, it seems to find a lot of issues (not sure how to post here), but given that it continues to find them and i'm using the "-p" "Automatic repair..", it doesn't seem like any are getting fixed

```
e2fsck -pc /dev/sdb1 > e2fsck.txt
```

I'm guessing this is some sort of simple oversight, but I've gone around in circles trying to figure this out and definitely need some help!

Comment: What does `dmesg` tell after you mount it? Edit the output into your question.

Comment: updated to include some more info from `dmesg` and `e2fsk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dmesg` output shows some you're having (physical) link layer problems. From [Libata error messages](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Libata_error_messages):

- `RecovData` : Data integrity error occurred, but the interface recovered
- `10B8B` : 10b to 8b decoding error occurred
- `Handshk` : R_ERR handshake response received in response to frame transmission

... and this during a write command (`WRITE FPDMA QUEUED`). After this the kernel decides disabling writing to this disk, hence your read-only experience...

This learns us that the issue at hand is most likely not caused by your Fedora upgrade (as basically the same kernels are used). You need to look to the hardware...

Possible causes:

- misconfigured BIOS
- broken ATA cable / connector
- disk broken

I would propose the following, easiest first :

- do a BIOS reset to factory defaults
- use another data and power cable to the disk
- try the disk in another system to see if it works there
- buy new disk and get over it

Good luck...

Comment: This was helpful, and it eventually led me to use the default fedora "disks" utility to run "SMART Data & Self-Tests..." that seemed to eventually restore all disks to good working order.  Thanks.